# Javascript search an array for a value and get its key

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I want to make a function that works like this:

```
function arraySearch(array, valuetosearchfor)
{
// some code
}
```

if it finds the value in the array, it will return the key, where it found the value. If there is more than one result (more than one key), or no results at all (nothing found), then the function will return FALSE.

I found this code:

```
function arraySearch(arr,val) 
        {
            for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
                {
                    if (arr[i] == val) 
                    {                    
                        return i;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
        }
```

and used it like this:

```
var resultofarraycheck = arraySearch(board, chosen);
                if (resultofarraycheck === false) 
                {
                       document.getElementById(buttonid).value;
                       chosen = 0;
                }
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
When it should find something, it returns false instead of the key (i).

How can I fix this, or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks, and I'm sorry if my English wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Move `return false` to *after* the `for` loop. (And think about handling the case with multiple identical results.)

Comment: [Iqbal Djulfri's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13109873/1233508) is the only one that actually meets your requirement regarding duplicate keys.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
function arraySearch(arr,val) {
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] === val)                    
            return i;
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use indexOf to get key  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xYdk/1/)

```
if(!Array.prototype.indexOf){
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(val){
        var i = this.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (this[i] == val) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    } 
}

    var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e'];

    var index = arr.indexOf('d'); // return 3
```

Comment: It's visa versa, I want to get the key from the value

Comment: @DCoder I added supprort for IE < 9

Comment: @shohamh no, its not. He provided bad example, but it works as you want. `['a', 'b', 'c'].indexOf('a')` will return 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
function arraySearch(arr, val) {
  var index;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // use '===' if you strictly want to find the same type
    if (arr[i] == val) {
      if (index == undefined) index = i;
      // return false if duplicate is found
      else return false;
    }
  }

  // return false if no element found, or index of the element
  return index == undefined ? false : index;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a method on the Array Prototype now:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

```
var array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];

function findFirstLargeNumber(element) {
  return element > 13;
}

console.log(array1.findIndex(findFirstLargeNumber));
// expected output: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to find the indices of different values for a particular array a lot, it may be better to make an object with key-value pairs that map to the values and indices of the array.

```
const letters = ["a", "b", "c"]
const letterIndices = letters.reduce((acc, letter, index) => 
    Object.assign(acc, {[letter]: index}), {}
)

letterIndices["b"] // gives 1
```